# Event over a margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, gwt

Having:

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="innerDiv" style="margin: 10px">Content goes here</div>
</div>
```

I want to identify those mouse events that happen outside innerDiv but inside outerDiv (said in a different way, those events over the innerDiv margin).

This is easy to achieve if I add outerDiv a padding or a border, but I would like to know if there is another way to do this without having to add extra pixels to outerDiv.

Thanks

Comment: It is for drag & drop, so I need to capture mouse down, mouse move and mouse  up.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by use of a flag:

```
<div id="outerDiv" style="border:thin solid red;">
    <div id="innerDiv" style="border:thin solid blue; margin: 10px;">Content goes here</div>
</div>

<script language="javascript">

var flag = false;

document.getElementById("outerDiv").onclick = function(){
    if (flag) {
        flag = false;
        return false;
    }
    alert("Clicked outerDiv");
}

document.getElementById("innerDiv").onclick = function(){
    flag = true;
    alert("Clicked innerDiv");
}

</script>
```

The essence is that the event for `innerDiv` will fire first. If so, prevent the event for `outerDiv`.

The technique works for `onmousedown`, `onmouseup` and `onmousemove`.

Comment: Thanks, but you example works because you added a border to the outerDiv, and that is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Works in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and Opera on Mac for me - with and without the borders. Expect it will work on all other formats too. I only added the borders so as to know where to click ;-)

Comment: However, DIVs are not rendered as you may expect if you do not add a border. For example, see the difference between `style="background-color:yellow;"` and `style="border:thin solid red;"` for `outerDiv`. This difference means that `outerDiv` will not be clickable above and below `innerDiv` if it does not have a border.

If you do not want to add a border, you can set a `height` for `outerDiv` or give it some `padding`.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery I would do the following

```
$("#outerDiv").bind("event", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest("#innerDiv")) {
    alert("from inner div");
  }
  else {
    alert("from outer div only");
  }
});
```

Explanation:

`#outerDiv` will get a bubbled event. If the event's target or target's ancestor is `#innerDiv` then we know it originated within the inner div. Otherwise it did not. Since it hit `#outerDiv` we know that it happened somewhere in `#outerDiv` but not in `#innerDiv`